# Trimming GPS information with awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep, gps

In a little bash script I simply try to trim GPS input data so that I have longitude and latitude values in separate variables:

```
  echo $geo_data
  GPS_latitude=$( echo $geo_data | awk -F"+|-" '{print substr($0,index($0,$2-1),1) $2}' )
  GPS_longitude=$( echo $geo_data | awk -F"+|-" '{print substr($0,index($0,$3-1),1) $3}' )
  echo $GPS_latitude
  echo $GPS_longitude
```

But what I get out seems to confuse the +/- signs in front of each component:

```
-04.7367+055.5230
-04.7367
-055.5230
```

I thought the index()-parameters would exactly avoid this situation, but obviously I did something wrong. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: See with GNU awk: `echo "$geo_data" | awk '{print $1,$2}' FPAT='[+-][0-9.]+'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subtract `1` from the output of `index` not the field value

```
$ echo '-04.7367+055.5230' | awk -F"+|-" '{print substr($0,index($0,$2)-1,1) $2}' 
-04.7367
$ echo '-04.7367+055.5230' | awk -F"+|-" '{print substr($0,index($0,$3)-1,1) $3}' 
+055.5230
```

You can also use [bash parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ s='-04.7367+055.5230'
$ a="${s%+*}"
$ b="${s#${s%+*}}"
$ echo "$a"
-04.7367
$ echo "$b"
+055.5230

$ # or, use the value of variable 'a'
$ c="${s#$a}"
$ echo "$c"
+055.5230
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I will try this first since it uses my existing style of writing.

Answer (score 1):

With bash and a regex:

```
geo_data="-04.7367+055.5230"

[[ "$geo_data" =~ ^([+-][0-9.]+)([+-][0-9.]+)$ ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Output:

```
-04.7367 +055.5230
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sed` to extract these values:

```
geo_data='-04.7367+055.5230'
GPS_latitude=$(sed 's/\(.*\)[-+].*/\1/' <<< "$geo_data")
GPS_longitude=$(sed 's/.*\([-+].*\)/\1/' <<< "$geo_data")
echo "GPS Latitude: ${GPS_latitude} and GPS longitude: ${GPS_longitude}"
# => GPS Latitude: -04.7367 and GPS longitude: +055.5230
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/wlclH7)

The latitude pattern is `\(.*\)[-+].*`, it captures all chars up to the last `+` or `-` into Group 1 and then matches the rest. The match is replaced with group 1 contents, so you get all before the last `+` or `-`.

**POSIX BRE regex details**

- `\(` - start of a capturing group #1 (`\1` refers this value from the replacement pattern)

  - `.*` - any 0 or more chars
- `\)` - end of the capturing group
- `[-+]` - a bracket expression matching either `-` or `+`
- `.*` - - any 0 or more chars.

The `GPS_longitude` pattern is identical, but captures all after last `-` or `+` including the plus or hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` solution:

```
$ geo_data=-04.7367+055.5230

$ echo $geo_data
-04.7367+055.5230

$ GPS_latitude=$(grep -o '^[+-][^+-]*' <<< $geo_data)
$ GPS_longitude=$(grep -o '[+-][^+-]*$' <<< $geo_data)

$ echo "GPS Latitude: $GPS_latitude; GPS Longitude: $GPS_longitude"
GPS Latitude: -04.7367; GPS Longitude: +055.5230
```